# Translating a simple UPDATE/JOIN from SQL into R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, data.table

I was given these crude database exports to fix up. In `SQL` have two tables that each have three columns: ID, first name and last name. In `sheet1`, the ID column is empty at the start whereas there are ID's in `sheet2`. I needed to join `sheet1` and `sheet2` where both first and last name matched and if there was an ID present in `sheet2` from the match, to set it in the ID column in `sheet1`. Very simple SQL query:

```
UPDATE sheet1
JOIN sheet2
ON sheet1.NAME_LAST = sheet2.Last_Name
AND sheet1.NAME_FIRST = sheet2.First_Name
SET sheet1.CONSTITUENT_ID = sheet2.ID
```

As this is a task that needs to be done often, what I'd like to do is set up my less savvy co-workers with a simple R script. I'm still a total beginner at R however. At present, I've got `sheet1` and `sheet2` in two data.frames (oh-so-descriptively named book1 and book2) via the native R method: `book2 = read.csv("sheet2.csv")` Through some googling it was suggested I take a look at the data.table library, but I'm still at a bit of a loss for where to start. Can someone help me translate SQL in to R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While SQL is a special-purpose language that for the most part id declarative and set-based, R is a functional programming language. It is often difficult to do direct language translations. Using base R, you would probably use a `merge()` command to bring different tables together.

If we have these sample tables

```
sheet1<-data.frame(
    NAME_LAST=letters[1:10],
    NAME_FIRST=letters[11:20],
    SEX=sample(c("M","F"), 10, replace=T)
)

sheet2<-data.frame(
    Last_Name=letters[1:10],
    First_Name=letters[11:20],
    ID = sample(100:200, 10)
)[sample(1:10), ]

sheet1;sheet2;
```

Then we can merge them with

```
mm<-merge(sheet1, sheet2, 
    by.x=c("NAME_LAST","NAME_FIRST"),
    by.y=c("Last_Name","First_Name")
)
mm;
```

You can them probably subset this merged data set to get what you need.

Comment: Thank you. :) This got me to where I was going. One note, on the merge I included a all.x= TRUE, as there were different numbers of records in each table and I needed all the records in sheet1 to remain.